# AxAcroPDF on selecting

Tags: vb.net, winforms, pdf, axacropdf

I have a VB winform where i load a PDF to a AxAcroPDF.
If i select on this form, i can right-click and copy this selection to clip board.

Is there any way to override this and save this selection to like `"C:\temp\temp.bmp"` when i do this selection? 
I've managed to make selections like this on a PictureBox by having something like

```
... Handles PictureBox1.Mousedown
```

These options are not avalible for the AxAcroPDF.

So, what i want is that every selection i make will create/write over `"C:\temp\temp.bmp"`, any ideas?

EDIT:
One way is to use that clipboard function, for example when a button is pressed.
I'm thinking this way; The user makes a selection, hits the button, it sends "Ctrl + C", takes the latest item from clipboard and makes this to a image. This works, the problem however is that the user must make selection and then manually press Ctrl + C (or right click and click copy) and then push the button and get the latest clipboard image. How can i tell it to make this Ctrl + C from the AxAcroPDF ?

Like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    SendKeys.Send("^(c)") 'this will not make the copy from the AxAcroPDF

    Dim tempImg As IDataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject()

    If tempImg.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap) Then
        PictureBox1.Image = tempImg.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, True) 'just display it in a picturebox, the plan is actually to save it

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The COM interface for Adobe Reader is *very* primitive.  Probably by design so programmers will buy the full version of Acrobat.

Comment: Yea, I can figure. My hope is that someone maybe has figured out a walk around or something :)